# Disparar função ao apertar F5 (atualizar)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em PHP que, através de seleção de um dado do combobox referente a embarcação e um campo de data, faço um `SELECT` no banco retornando alguns dados que são inseridos em uma tabela.

Gostaria assim que o usuário selecione a embarcação (1) e por algum caso ele pressione o botão <kbd>F5</kbd> (atualizar) [2] o sistema chame uma função.

Fiz uma pesquisa para essa funcionalidade em JavaScript, porém não encontrei.

Para ficar mais visual, segue minha tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O evento do JavaScript que é chamado antes de recarregar a página por <kbd>F5</kbd> é o `beforeunload`. Testei o código abaixo e funcionou com `Jquery 3.3.1`. Obs: alguns eventos como o `alert` são bloqueados nesse evento por questões de segurança.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
   $.ajax({
       async: false,
       url: 'teste.php',
       data: { dados: "teste"},
       method: "POST"
   });
   return true;
});
```

Comment: Um desses comandos que os navegadores bloqueiam seria o ajax? Tentei encorporar na sua função, um ajax com um type GET para obter a condição que citei na pergunta mas não tivesse sucesso.

Comment: @AlmerindoAbreu Aprimorei a resposta e testei o código no Chrome. O Ajax não é bloqueado quando utilizando Jquery.